Error in Pycharm Terminal When Space in Path
When I try to run terminal in pycharm I get this error :

I understand I encounter this error because pycharm is trying to activate the virtual environment and I have spaces in my folder path which is C:\Users\syedm\Desktop\Muneer Coding.
Is there any file where I can go and edit
C:/Users/syedm/Desktop/Muneer Coding/.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1
to
"C:/Users/syedm/Desktop/Muneer Coding/.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1".
Or is there any other way ?
Or is there no way and I have to change my folder name to Muneer-Coding ?

Add either single or double quotes around the filename.

Looks like a known pycharm issue. You can work around it by manually dot-sourcing the activation script from the terminal: . ./.venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1

Adding single quotes and making it 'Muneer Coding' doesn't work.

@MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for sharing the link. So can I expect it to be solved in next version of pycharm ?

@SYEDMUNEER I don't think anyone here can guarantee that, that's a question for the makers of PyCharm :)

C:/Users/syedm/Desktop/Muneer\ Coding/.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1` Try backticking the space
